# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'Mail.php'

Tags: php, forms, cpanel

```
ini_set("include_path", '/home/busaweb/php:' . ini_get("include_path") );
require_once "Mail.php";
include('Mail/mime.php');
```

Anyone who can explain why these lines serve code?
I have been getting an error message since a few days that these files are missing/not viewable, see error code below:

```
[01-Aug-2022 18:48:59 UTC] PHP Warning: require_once(Mail.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vestad/public_html/forms/functions.php on line 4
[01-Aug-2022 18:48:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='/home/vestad/php:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php80/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/vestad/public_html/forms/functions.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vestad/public_html/forms/offer_email.php(6): include()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/vestad/public_html/forms/functions.php on line 4
```

Is there anyone who can explain what may be causing this suddenly and how to fix it? I use hosting from a cpanel environment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error speaks for itself. The file cannot be found. Maybe you can check if you are able to access the file (maybe check the permissions in CHMOD?)

Comment: You're including `/home/busaweb/php`, but the path in the error shows `/home/vestad/php`. What happens if you `var_dump(ini_get('include_path'));` both before and after you attempt to add the path?